# App for offline bookmark reading on iPad

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, bookmarks, network

I'm currently using Diigo for saving my bookmarks and reading them later on the iPad offline. However, it allows only the 20 last for reading.

Does anyone know an app that enables reading older history items offline?

Answer (score 3):

I really like [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com). Not only does it allow storage and hierarchical organization of seemingly unlimited bookmarks/pages, it has a nice, big cache and reading offline works like a charm.

It will save articles that are broken into multiple pages automatically which I particularly like.

It also sports an iBooks-like UI which allows typographic control, strips ads and fluff out, and helps with the reading experience. Frankly, I prefer reading in Instapaper than on the original site.

Lastly, it keeps track of where you left off in multiple articles if you don't finish one and move to another.

Answer (score 0):

I discover since few days, the Pocket App (http://getpocket.com) available for the iPad and iPhone, versus with Instapaper, you can bookmarks video and other kind of content and see on the iPad after the application have downloaded.

Also, you can use the Chrome/Firefox plugin to bookmarks directly from the browser, the link where you are.

In my opinion, is better than Pocket Instapaper

Comment: Also, you can use the Chrome/Firefox plugin to bookmarks directly from the browser, the link where you are.--> what plug in? how to downlaod? but then I have to be online  to read bookmarks, no?